# By filling in the code marked FILL_IN in Listing 3.42, write a test for the root route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Adding the root route in Listing 3.41 leads to the creation of a Rails helper called root_url (in analogy with helpers like static_pages_home_url). By filling in the code marked FILL_IN in Listing 3.42, write a test for the root route.

```
Listing 3.41: Setting the root route to the Home page.
config/routes.rb
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
end

Listing 3.42: A test for the root route. green
test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb
 require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get root" do
    get FILL_IN
    assert_response FILL_IN
  end
end
```

What Should be the FILL_IN?
I tried static_pages_root_url, root_url.

```
rails test fails.
F

Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_root [/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:12]:
<Root | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
<Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.

E

Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_root:
ArgumentError: Invalid response name: root_url
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
  test "should get root" do
    get '/'
    assert_response :success
  end
```

More info on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#implementing-an-integration-test

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with `root_url`. You might want to check that you are serving the home page on `routes.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else in the future you're telling it to go to your home page which is in your static pages controller then we copy the syntax from the other tests... so it ends up being written like this...

```
test "should get root" do
  get static_pages_home_url
  assert_response :success
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test you should be telling it to look for the `<Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App>` since root and home will display the same.

Answer (score 0):

this is the complete solution (guarantee it will work)

```
  test "should get root" do
    get root_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | #{@base_title}"   
  end
```