# Rails root test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, root

I am a beginner and am trying to test whether the following code maps to the "home page":

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
end
```

what should I replace the first and second "FILL_IN" with in the block below?

```
test "should get root" do
    get FILL_IN
    assert_response FILL_IN
end
```

Would appreciate your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [By filling in the code marked FILL\_IN in Listing 3.42, write a test for the root route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113739/by-filling-in-the-code-marked-fill-in-in-listing-3-42-write-a-test-for-the-root)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are following the ["Ruby on Rails Tutorial"](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/frontmatter) by Micheal Hartl?

Specifically this step: [Listing 3.42: A test for the root route](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#code-root_test)

---

Although not explicitly disclosed in the tutorial (correct me if im wrong)...

I believe the solution below will pass your test. I tried it myself to double check.

```
test "should get root" do
  get '/'
  assert_response :success
end
```

---

Additional reading can be found here: [Rails Guide - Integration Tests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing)

---

Similar Posts: [By filling in the code marked FILL_IN in Listing 3.42, write a test for the root route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113739/by-filling-in-the-code-marked-fill-in-in-listing-3-42-write-a-test-for-the-root)

Thanks [@AlterLagos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895789/alter-lagos)

Comment: Thanks Nathan! it worked!
Yes, I am following  "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" .

Comment: Is there also a way to assert that the view that was rendered was indeed `home.html.erb`, and not just the `render html: 'Hello, world!'` string?

Comment: This depends on how you define the "/" route and the file routed to. Common naming conventions usually point the "/" route to a home page (Ex: home.html.erb).